# Retrieve values from single document Angular and Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the individual values using Angular from a Firestore Document.

My TypeScript code:

```
userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;
user: Observable<User>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.userDoc = this.afs.doc('users/' + this.af.auth.currentUser.uid);
    this.user = this.userDoc.valueChanges();
}
```

Then HTML:

```
{{ user | async | json }}
```

Returns this:

```
{ "email": "x@gmail.com", "firstname": "x", "lastname": "x", "phone": "x", "subscription": x, "uid": "x" }
```

Which is exactly what I need...

but when I try to get an individual value like:

```
<p>
   Your email is: {{ user.email | async }}
</p>
```

I can't get the single value. How do I "unwrap" to observable to get the single value?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363161/angular-2-displaying-async-object-data-from-promise

Comment: Wow I was searching forever. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer, it's simply:

```
{{(user | async)?.email }}
```

to unwrap the data. If someone can better explain this that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled in Angular on the component side instead of the html by using this routine.

- The reference to the collection is made
- A subscription to that reference is created.
- we then check each document to see if the field we are looking for is empty
- Once the empty field is found, we store that document id in a class variable.

First, create a service .ts component to handle the backend work (this component can be useful to many other components: Firestoreservice.

This component will contain these exported routines (see this post for that component firestore.service.ts:
[How to retrieve document id's for collections in AngularFire2's Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336131/how-to-retrieve-document-ids-for-collections-in-angularfire2s-firestore)

In your component, import this service and make a

```js
private firestore: Firestoreservice,
```

reference in your constructor.

Done!

```html
this.firestoreData = this.firestore.getCollection(this.dataPath); //where dataPath = the collection name

this.firestoreData.subscribe(firestoreData => {
                
   for (let dID of firestoreData ) {
      if (dID.field1 == this.ClassVariable1) {
          if (dID.field2 == '') {
                this.ClassVariable2 = dID.id; //assign the Firestore documentID to a class variable for use later
          }
      }
   }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**